# Transfering a file using Chef Knife winrm to a remote window machine

Tags: windows, linux, powershell, chef-infra, winrm

Is there any way to transfer files to a remote windows machine using `winrm / powershell` or any native windows commands?

I have a Chef `knife-windows` installed on one of the Linux machine. I want to transfer files from the linux machine to the windows machine using `knife winrm` or any native windows commands without installing any additional packages on the windows machine.

I tried to cat a file & pipe it to the `knife winrm` command and do a `Set-Content` or `Out-File` `powershell` commands, but it was not working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

If you have admin access to the Windows boxes you can always copy files to an [administrative share](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314984) via `SMB`.

Comment: Samba share is not allowed! Thanks

Comment: Why? You're crippling your own ability to maintain the systems by disallowing that.

Comment: samba shares require a file to maintain a password. With password expiration dates, if you forget to update the password, samba will cause said account to get locked out every 90 days. It's kind of a pain. Automount is much better.

Comment: we're talking about accessing shares from a remote Windows server. You don't need to maintain a Samba password for that. Not to mention that I fail to see how automount would get you around expiring passwords.

Answer (score 1):

From PowerShell

```
knife winrm -m <IP> -x <USER> -P <PASS> "echo $(gc .\secret_key)>c:\secret_key"
```

You have to remember, that main issues is that regardless of your execution context (powershell / bash shell) the destination will always be CMD. So you gotta play by the destination rules.

`$(gc .\secret_key)` gets the contents of the file locally, and `echo` is executed remotely.